# How can I permanently change the keyboard format in linux?

Tags: command-line, keyboard

Currently I know the method since my computer is in qwerty having the azerty distribution, but I only found this.

setxkbamp fr

However it does not help me, since when I restart the pc it returns to qwerty, which is annoying

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 1):

You can run:

```
localectl set-x11-keymap fr
```

Then logout and login.

Comment: didn't work currently

Comment: You should really consider answering the questions in the comments. The more information you give, the more likely it is to get some help. There are literally dozens of distributions, between forks and different versions. And then you have different window managers and other componentes. There is no silver bullet, you will have to tell us more.